# I can't seem to get the right longitude and latitude of images in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to extract the longitude and latitude of an image I took of myself. It went wrong horribly and said that I was in Japan, but I took the photo in Australia.

I tried this code:

```
import PIL.Image
import PIL.ExifTags
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

img =  PIL.Image.open(r"C:\Users\RGCRA\Pictures\Camera Roll\WIN_20240102_11_46_09_Pro.jpg")

exif = {
    PIL.ExifTags.TAGS[k]: v
    for k, v in img._getexif().items()
    if k in PIL.ExifTags.TAGS
}

north = exif['GPSInfo'][2]
east = exif['GPSInfo'][4]


lat = ((((north[0] * 60) + north[1]) * 60) + north[2]) / 60 / 60
long = ((((east[0] * 60) + east[1]) * 60) + east[2]) / 60 / 60

lat, long = float(lat), float(long)

geoLoc = Nominatim(user_agent='GetLoc')

locname = geoLoc.reverse(f"{lat}, {long}")

print(locname.address)
```

I realized that I didn't have a hyphen in front of the latitude. How could I fix it?

Comment: Also the address was written in Chinese although I don't have Chinese installed in my computer.

Comment: Please [edit] to paste the text used in the image into your question so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that since I am working in only the southern hemisphere, all I needed to do was:

lat = lat - (lat*2)

I don't know how to do it worldwide, but this works for me.

Comment: “I don't know how to do it worldwide” - By using a conditional statement. Latitude in Southern hemisphere will be negative while it will be positive in the northern hemisphere. Likewise, longitude it will be positive in one hemisphere and negative in the other.

Comment: Re *"`lat - (lat*2)`"*: What? Isn't it the same as `-lat`? (Except for floating point rounding errors.)